# Large python JSON post request times out

Tags: python, http, rest, post, httplib2

I'm trying to post some data using python, essentially a very large JSON file (around 420kB).  The problem is that it works fine when it's posting to a local server, but times out for any external server.  The code looks like this:

```
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "application/json"
};

response, content = httplib2.Http().request( 
    uri="http://%s:%s/json" % (host, port), method='POST',
    headers=headers, 
    body=json_string )
```

and the error I get is something along the lines of:

```
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Any thoughts on this?  I was thinking that maybe the socket connection locally was timing out, but I have no idea how to fix this.  All of the socket calls from the "import socket" library doesn't seem to have an effect.

**UPDATE**

I've tried it on a couple of different networks now, and it seems that it is a timeout issue, since the script works on all other networks besides a relatively slow one I'm on now.  So the choice becomes either somehow stream the data or figure out a way to effectively increase the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the time required for the response is greater than the default timeout. 
Try giving the timeout in the

```
response, content = httplib2.Http().request( 
uri="http://%s:%s/json" % (host, port), method='POST',
headers=headers, 
body=json_string , timeout=100 ) (set the time as required)
```

or u can set a socket timeout large enough to bring the response

```
import socket
timeout = 100 (set the time as required)
socket. setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first suggestion doesn't actually exist in the version of python I am using.  There is no timeout argument.  The second doesn't seem to have any effect, although the program does run.